# What is wrong with my select statement?

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is the question, keep in mind I'm using SQL developer 3....

The Student Services department wants to know how involved each faculty member is when it comes to supplying advice to students outside of class.  Supply a list of faculty IDs and the number of students that faculty member is advising.  Title the output column for faculty IDs “Faculty ID”, and the output column for the student count as “NumStuds”.  Produce output only if the faculty id is less than 100 and the student has a value entered in either the last name or first name field.  Present the output in increasing order by faculty ID

This is what I get...

```
SELECT F_ID AS "Falculty ID" , COUNT S_ID AS "NumStud" FROM student
WHERE ( s_first, s_last, f_id ) IS NOT NULL
AND IS <= 100
ORDER BY F_ID ACD
```

Then I get error Error starting at line 329 in command:

```
SELECT F_ID AS "Falculty ID" , COUNT S_ID AS "NumStud" FROM student
WHERE ( s_first, s_last, f_id ) IS NOT NULL
AND IS <= 100
ORDER BY F_ID ACD
```

> Error at Command Line:329 Column:42 Error report: SQL Error:
>   ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
>   00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: you should also watch your naming convention: F_ID, f_id. Probably your database is not case-sensitive, but some databases are everything i would advise to do everything in lowercase

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that since you are testing for *null* value. It should manually be tested.

```
SELECT F_ID AS "Falculty ID" , COUNT(S_ID) AS "NumStud" 
FROM student 
WHERE   (
            s_first IS NOT NULL OR 
            s_last IS NOT NULL OR
            f_id  IS NOT NULL
        ) AND IS <= 100 
ORDER BY F_ID ASC
```

Second, it should `ASC` for *Ascending* not `ACD`

Comment: enclose count statement: COUNT(S_ID)?

Comment: The `AND IS <= 100` is not a valid expression

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT F_ID AS "Faculty ID" , COUNT(S_ID) AS "NumStud" 
FROM student
WHERE COALESCE( s_first, s_last ) IS NOT NULL AND F_ID < 100
GROUP BY F_ID 
ORDER BY F_ID ASC
```